# Debian's mod_wsgi python3 does not work with debian's python3?

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, debian, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a Django-python3 application on Debian with apache mod_wsgi ([django official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)). I use a virtualenv with python3 and here is what I get in the /var/log/apache2/error.log file :

> mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.2rc1+.
>
> mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.4.2.
>
> Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1k mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.4.2 configured -- resuming normal operations

It seems to me that mod_wsgi and python from Debian's repositories can't work together. Am I missing something ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's a standard message when Apache starts up, it's not a problem. Do you have any other errors in the Apache2 error log? What happens when try to access the site?

Comment: Really ? No I don't have any other message, and yet I get a server error 500. Do you know if there is another log somewhere ?

Comment: So sorry.. My installation worked on dev with manage.py and not in prod so I assumed it was apache fault. Turns out I did not give the rights to apache to read in the folder. Thanks a lot for saying the message was not an error BTW !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My installation worked on dev with manage.py and not in production so I assumed it was Apache fault. Turns out I did not give the rights to Apache to read in the folder.